# How to plot the latitude and longitude points on the map

Tags: google-maps, reporting-services, graph, google-visualization, tableau-api

I have a table with latitude and longitude data. What I want to do is plot it on the map so that I can visualize the locations a user has visited. In my table I have userid, latitude and longitude of starting points and latitude and longitude for stopping points. Can any one suggest what will be the best platform to plot data on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in Tableau then you just need to use the latitude and longitude fields for the data that you have:

[image]

Note: if tableau does not recognize your fields as latitude and longitude (they will have small globe icons) then right click on the field and select the geo type that you want to assign to the field.

And then simply double click the fields and drag on the value that you want to visualize at those points and you will get a map:

[image]

See more here: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/mapping-basics

Comment: Luckily, I have tableau and therefore I made it. Thanks. I had to right click the longitude and latitude fields in tableau to convert them to dimensions before dragging longitude to columns and latitude to rows. Please add the steps in your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have added it.

Answer (score 1):

Can i suggest you to build a google earth .kml file ? It's a very quick and easy way to do it. Since .kml files are XML based, it's probably the fastest way to do it ;-)

Comment: Because I have tableau, I opted for the second answer but I think for those who do not have a commercial tool like tableau, yours is a good option.